# Fetching German character from oracle database

Tags: asp.net, database, oracle, text

I have database as Oracle and development is in asp.net. Data stored is as,
Förderer, Jörg etc.

Everything works fine on my local environment, where i can fetch the records having German characters, and i can display it on users browser.

However, when i deploy the solution on client machine, problem starts. When i fetch data from Oracle db. and fill a drop down or display it on label, it just does not show correct data. For e.g., 
Förderer gets converted to Forderer
Jörg gets converted to Jorg ....

However, when i simply Response.Write("Förderer"), browser display it correctly. This means, that what i set in web.config works,

But, when it fetches information from db. , it does not display correctly. Then, i tried one more solution, to just avoid any direct table access. For that , i simply created TableAdapter, with command text like this,

Dim sQuery As String = ""
sQuery = "SELECT 'Förderer'  FROM DUAL"

Now, when i fetch information from dataset, that i filled with above command, it again does not display correct data, but converted "Forderer".

I appreciate any suggestion/help toward this.

-Divyesh

Comment: Tag `german` removed as part of the [**2012 cleanup**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the [current thread's Culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to "de-de" in Page_Init?

```
Dim germanCulture As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = germanCulture
```